# Limits $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$

Tags: calculus, limits

My textbook says [image]

(the limit approaches $-\infty$)

What's the explanation behind $-x$ in the equation $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$?

Comment: $x$ is negative so $-x$ is positive...

Comment: For $x<0$, $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I see thanks.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  When $x < 0$, $|x| = - x$.

Comment: I see no $-x$ in the equation shown: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

Comment: @Mirko yes true, and $|x| = -x, \text{ for } x < 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because x is negative, the positive square root of $x^2$ is -x.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this in few mins. Question resolved.

Comment: x goes to negative infinity at both the numerator and denominator, so they should cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Because when $x$ is inside the square root it is not negative and when $x$ is out it should stay not negative because $x\to-\infty$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{\underbrace{x^2}_{\ge0}}$$

Comment: x goes to negative infinity at both the numerator and denominator, so they should cancel.